# Manipulação de arquivos

Tags: c, arquivo, struct

Olá. Estou com um problemão para manipular criar e manipular um arquivo em C.
Primeiramente fiz o código inteiro utilizando uma struct e funções, funcionou tudo certinho. Coloquei os comandos para criar o arquivo e também está ok.

Meu problrma é na hora de abrir e inserir dados nele. Já tentei de várias formas e o máximo que consegui foi bugar os dados salvos na memória mesmo. Segue o código.

> P.S. São ao todo 8 funções, vou colocar só a primeira, pra não ficar muito poluído visualmente o post.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <locale.h>
#include <string.h>
#define MAX 1

struct turma{
int matricula;
char nome[15];
float nota[5];
float media;
char resultado;
}; typedef struct turma turma;

int main()
{
setlocale (LC_ALL, "Portuguese");
printf ("\nFeito por Maximiliano Meyer\n");
turma alg[MAX];
int menu;

FILE *arquivo;
arquivo = fopen("notas.txt","rb+");
if(arquivo==NULL)
    {   arquivo=fopen("notas.txt","wb+");
        printf("\nO arquivo notas não pôde ser aberto");
        if(arquivo==NULL)
        { printf(" O arquivo não pôde ser aberto");
        exit(1);
        }
    }


menu = 0;
  while (menu != 8)
  {
system("cls");
printf("\n\n  Escolha uma opção no menu abaixo:\n\n");
printf("  |~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~|\n");
printf("  | 1 - Inserir notas                      |\n");
printf("  | 2 - Consultar notas                    |\n");
printf("  | 3 - Alterar dados                      |\n");
printf("  | 4 - Excluir                            |\n");
printf("  | 5 - Listagem geral da turma            |\n");
printf("  | 6 - Média da turma                     |\n");
printf("  | 7 - Consultar alunos aprovados         |\n");
printf("  | 8 - Sair                               |\n");
printf("   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~\n");
scanf("%d", &menu);
printf("\n");

switch (menu)
{
  case 1 : system("cls");
  insere(alg, arquivo);
  printf("\n\aNotas inseridas!\n");
  system("Pause");
break;
```

...demais funções....

```
 case 8: system("cls");
      printf("Saindo da aplicação\nDesenvolvido por Maximiliano Meyer\n\n");
    break;

  default:
    system("cls");
    printf("Opção inválida.\nRevise o valor digitado.\n\n");
    system("Pause");
    }
  }
    fclose (arquivo);
}
void insere (FILE *arquivo, turma alg[MAX])
{   turma reg;
arquivo=fopen("notas", "rb+");
int x,y;
float cont=0;

for (x=0;x<MAX;x++)
{   printf("\nInforme os dados do %iº aluno: ", x+1);
    printf("\n\nMatrícula: ", x+1);
    scanf("%d", &alg[x].matricula);
    printf("Nome: ", x+1);
    fflush(stdin);
    gets(alg[x].nome);
        for (y=0;y<5;y++){
        printf("%iº nota: ", y+1);
        scanf("%f", &alg[x].nota[y]);
        cont = cont + alg[x].nota[y];
    }
    alg[x].media = cont/5;
    if (alg[x].media >=7)
        alg[x].resultado = 'A';
    else
        alg[x].resultado = 'R';
}
    fseek(arquivo,0,SEEK_SET);
    fwrite(&reg,sizeof(struct turma),1, arquivo);
    fclose(arquivo);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Analisando na hora que você abre o arquivo

```
fopen("notas", "rb+");
```

Se você quiser apenas `adicionar` texto ao invés de criar um novo tu usa o parâmetro `a`

```
fopen("notas", "a");
```

> Adiciona a um arquivo. Operações de leitura, adiciona dados ao final do arquivo. É criado o arquivo caso não existir.

#### Fonte: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_fopen.htm

Usando o `append` tu não precisa do `fseek`, basta usar `fprintf`.

Answer (score 0):

Compila com o maximo de warnings e erros que o teu compilador permite.

Dentro da funcao `main()` tens

```
  case 1 : system("cls");
  insere(alg, arquivo);
```

sem um prototipo activo para a funcao `insere()`. Nessa altura o compilador "inventa" a assinatura `int insere()`.

Mais tarde defines a funcao com uma assinatura diferente da que o compilador inventou, nomeadamente `void insere(FILE *, turma *)` e o compilador deve-se queixar!!

Solucao: escreve o prototipo da funcao **antes** de a chamares (a definicao da funcao tambem serve de prototipo), liga o maximo de warnings, e **toma atencao e corrige todos os warnings produzidos**.